# What’s the right OIDC flow for Vue SPA with .Net 5 WebAPI?

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, single-page-application, openid-connect

I read much about OIDC flows and that Authorization Code flow with PKCE is the right one for SPA’s. But what if I have a .Net 5 WebAPI Backend. Would it be possible to use Authorization Code flow without PKCE for that combination?

If I use Auth Code flow with PKCE, what Authentification ist the right one for my WebAPI? JWT Token?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

**STANDARD FLOWS**

- The SPA should use Authorization Code Flow + PKCE to authenticate users and get tokens
- The API will just validates JWT access tokens, then uses claims for authorization

**PKCE**

The authorization code flow originally required a client secret but an SPA cannot use one securely. Therefore the traditional SPA flow uses a runtime secret, via PKCE parameters, and this prevents certain types of vulnerability.

**TRADITIONAL SPA FLOW**

A couple of years ago it used to be standard to implement security for an SPA solely in Javascript as in [this code sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1) of mine.

**BROWSER BASED APPS IN 2021**

SPA security is very tricky though, due to browser security concerns and recent browser restrictions. In 2021 it is recommended to use a Back End for Front End approach, where the SPA uses only `SameSite=strict` cookies to call APIs. The back end can be either of these:

- A website that redirects the SPA when `index.html` is requested, though these can make some SPA goals harder, eg deployment to a CDN
- An API that the SPA calls on demand, in a way that gives the SPA control, and does not lose benefits of an SPA architecture

An SPA can use a client secret if it proxies requests involving tokens via a back end - which can store the secret securely and attach it in calls to the Authorization Server.

**API REDIRECT SOLUTION**

OIDC .Net libraries are designed to be used in websites and not in APIs. Consider an SPA at `https://www.example.com` doing OIDC via an API at `https://api.example.com`:

- The SPA can only call the API via Ajax calls, eg

```
GET  https://api.example.com/login
```

- The website OIDC library will try to redirect the browser by returning an Ajax response containing a 302 redirect with the URL in a `Location` header
- Typically a browser may not allow the SPA's code to read this type of header
- An API based redirect URI would also be required, and the OIDC response would return to an API URL that would be processed in the browser, eg:

```
GET https://api example.com/callback?code=xxx
```

- The API could process this request, then set a cookie for `.example.com`, then redirect back to the web origin. You may run into issues setting cookies in redirects - eg `SameSite=strict` cookies may be dropped and need to be downgraded to `SameSite=lax`

**API SOLUTION**

You are likely to find it easier when using an API to manage tokens / cookies for an SPA to separate web and API concerns more completely. These resources show how this type of solution works:

- [Blog Post on SPA Security Landscape](https://curity.io/blog/token-handler-the-single-page-applications-new-bff/)
- [SPA Code Sample using an API Driven Back End for Front End](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff)
- [API that performs OIDC work for an SPA](https://github.com/curityio/bff-node-express)

Comment: Ah okay, but as I understand if I have a backend I can use also code flow with secret in my backend? But how to handle redirect of my backend in the spa?

Comment: You should aim for a setup where the SPA redirects itself as in [this class from the above code example](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff/blob/main/code/spa/src/oauth/oauthClient.ts). The URL the SPA uses can be calculated by a back end API though.

Comment: So what’s I don’t understand. Is it possible to secure my spa and .net WebAPI by configuring oidc in my WebAPI with code flow? Is that best practice and more secure to do so or am I wrong? My Idea is: spa requests data from WebAPI, is not authorized and receives a redirect to OIDC api. SPA becomes redirected to IDP, user logs in and redirects to WebAPI which will change auth. code to token and redirect to SPA. Is that wrong or not best practice?

Comment: This model would be tricky when you think about redirects and Ajax requests. I added some notes on it above.

Comment: Why is the 'ID token' not being used by the API to authenticate the user using that specific API?